# Using python's RotatingFileHandler with no logger object

Tags: python, logging

I have my own logging system that is not based on a logging object. 
Can I still enjoy the services of [RotatingFileHnadler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler)? I've tried to define the handler after I set the log file. But I don't see it performed any rotation (no files added named for example mylog.log.1, mylog.log.2 ...)
 What am I missing?

```
 handler = RotatingFileHandler(self.fullName+'.debug',mode='a', maxBytes=1, backupCount=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-5.5s] %(message)s")
    fileHandler = RotatingFileHandler('/var/log/blabla.log',
                                  maxBytes=10 * 1000 * 1000,
                                  encoding='utf8',
                                  backupCount=5)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
```